# Sequence and Asymptotic Equivalence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

We define a sequence by $a_0 = 0$ and $a_n = \ln(n!) - (n+\frac{1}{2})\ln(n) + n$ for positive integer $n$.

If we know $a_n$ converges, how do we prove $\ln(n!)$ is asymptotically equaivalent to $(n+1/2)\ln(n)-n$?

Comment: See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559263/sequences-and-asymptotic-similarity

Answer (score 0):

Swithching to algebra, consider the function
$$f(x)= \log(x!) - \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\log(x) + x$$ and use [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

When $x$ is "large", this leads to
$$f(x)\sim \frac{1}{2} \log (2
   \pi )+\frac{1}{12 n}$$